# How can I populate a ListView with contacts within a custom adapter class?

Tags: android, android-listview, contacts

I have a custom adapter. Within my `getView()`, I'm trying to populate **"holder.contact"** with a list of my contacts, but with no success. I do have this method of populating my `ListView` with contacts, but it disrupts the functionality of my `CheckBoxes`. This code is outside of my `CustomAdapter` class:

```
public void populateContactList() {
    // Build adapter with contact entries
    Cursor cursor = getContacts();
    String[] fields = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME       
    };

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_entry, cursor,
            fields, new int[] {R.id.contactEntryText});    
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);    
} // END POPULATECONTACTLIST

public Cursor getContacts()
{ 
    // Run query
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME        
    };

    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '" +
            (false ? "0" : "1") + "'";
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
} // END GETCONTACTS
```

But I'm trying to define it within here, but with no success (Custom Adapter class):

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View rowView = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(
                                           Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // HERE I AM INFLATING LISTVIEW LAYOUT.
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_entry, null, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.photo = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.iv_contactPic);
        holder.contact = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.contactEntryText);
        holder.tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.SMSCounttext);
        holder.cb = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.cb_contactHistoryChk);


        rowView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }
```

Is there a way to apply my **populateContactList()** method within the `getView()`?

My constructor looks like this. "elements" is already used by another textview:

```
public CustomAdapter(Context context, int type, ArrayList<String> elements){
    super(context, type, elements);
```

Comment: I dont think it is possible you should use expandable listview...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little ambiguous. You have the `populateContactList()` which binds a `Cursor` with `Contacts` data to a `SimpleCursorAdapter` and you want to use this method in the `getView()` method of another custom `Adapter`(if this is the case, don't do this)? Or you want to use your own adapter and bind to it the data with the contacts(if this is the case, then use the results from the query, `cursor`, with your own `Adapter`)?

You don't say what type of `Adapter` your custom `Adapter` extends. If it is a `Cursor` based `Adapter`, things are easy and you can use the `bindView` and `newView` to access the cursor data(and you pass the `Cursor` from `getContacts()` in the constructor(to the super class)). Otherwise put the data from the `Cursor` you get with `getContacts()` in a structure like an `ArrayList` and use that as the data for the adapter. (I would recommend to go with the first option).

Also, it's your job to maintain the status of `CheckBoxes` from your row layout(there are many questions here on how to do this).

Edit:

```
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = getContacts();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
         names.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME )));

}
```

**Edit:** 
Use the *elements* `ArrayList` and bind it to the rows:

```
    //...
    private ArrayList<String> data;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int type, ArrayList<String> elements){
        super(context, type, elements);
        this.data = elements;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();  
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(
                                               Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            // HERE I AM INFLATING LISTVIEW LAYOUT.
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_entry, parent, false); //<= use parent instead of null
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.photo = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.iv_contactPic);
            holder.contact = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.contactEntryText);
            holder.tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.SMSCounttext);
            holder.cb = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.cb_contactHistoryChk);
            rowView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }
        //bind the data to the row views
        String contactName = data.get(position);
        holder.contact.setText(contactName);
        // other stuff you might do to build thw row
//...
```

Comment: My custom adapter class extends "ArrayAdapter<String>," but my "getContacts()" which is a cursor is in a different class. My checkboxes are ok. I just need to populate the list differently from above.

Comment: @ChocoMan Call the `getContacts()` method from the activity where you also instantiate the custom adapter(you say it is in another class, just do it like you did in the `populateContactList` method). Then extract the name from the cursor in an `ArrayList<String>`. Pass this to your custom adapter constructor and then you can use it to populate the adapter.

Comment: how do you extract the names and put them into a ArrayList<String>? I've searched for that, but came up empty

Comment: @ChocoMan I've edited my answer. You should add your classes and how exactly do you plan to call the methods.

Comment: Hey, I've managed to extract the data and put in in an ArrayList<String>. I tested it by mocking up Logs and it's there in a AL called "myContacts." The problem I'm having is what you mean by passing it into my custom adapter's constructor. I've edited my post to show you my constructor. "elements" is already working with another textview. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I figured out the rest from your example. Still have minor issues, but your source got me to where I wanted to be at.